# Magento: Change Product Position in Categories based on price

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a client that wants to have all products that do not have a price to show up behind all products that do have a price. In this case, I will change the product position to 999. But they have over 3,000 products and it will take me hours to do manually.

Is there a way to possibly update this through MySQL? I would have to connect two tables I know. `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_product_entity_decimal` I believe it is.

Now I know `catalog_category_product` has a field called `product_id` and `catalog_product_entity_decimal` has a field called `entity_id` which are essentially the same thing.

I figure there has to be a way to connect each of them somehow to make this happen.

**EDIT**: And yes, I know there is a Sort By that will do this, but they don't want to have the highest price to the lowest price showing as a default. They want to be able to position items they would like on the first fold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Always do database backup before this kind of operation

### 2. use this to check if your result is correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM `catalog_category_product` AS `cpe`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `e`.`entity_id`
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
        INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `ea` ON `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'price'
        INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `at_price` ON (`at_price`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_price`.`attribute_id` = `ea`.`attribute_id`)
    WHERE ((at_price.value = '0') OR (((at_price.value = 'price') OR (at_price.value = '1'))))
         ) AS `result` ON cpe.product_id = result.entity_id;
```

### 3. and this to update position values:

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_product` AS `cpe`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `e`.`entity_id`
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
        INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `ea` ON `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'price'
        INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `at_price` ON (`at_price`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_price`.`attribute_id` = `ea`.`attribute_id`)

    WHERE ((at_price.value = '0') OR (((at_price.value = 'price') OR (at_price.value = '1'))))
) AS `result` ON cpe.product_id = result.entity_id
SET `cpe`.`position` = 999;
```

### 4. Notice this code shouldn't work with multistores.

### 5. Use it on your own risk:)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a shot. This is for one store, so it should work in my favor. I will let you know how it comes out!

Comment: That seemed to do it! I have gone through a couple of categories and they are looking good! Thanks a lot man. I would kiss you right now if I could. You saved me hours of work.